# setting path is not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, path

My system path has `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin` as the first path component.

I opened a Command Prompt as Administrator.

Then ran java -version

The java.exe under `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin` ran since that is the first java.exe in the path. Everything is fine.

Then I change my path using the command:

```
set PATH=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;%PATH%
```

This adds `jdk1.7.0_01\bin` as the first component in the path

Now I run java -version

I was expecting the `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\java.exe` to be run since that is the first in the PATH. But it actually ran `jdk1.7.0_05\bin\java.exe`, that means the set PATH command did have any effect.

When I did echo `%PATH%`, `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin` indeed showed up as the first component in the path.

Why is then java.exe not being run from the jdk1.7.0_01\bin location?

I tried the same thing from a command prompt which is not running as administrator and everything worked as expected, i.e. after running the set PATH command, java was picked up from `jdk1.7.0_01\bin`.

Does this means set PATH doesn't work when command prompt is opened as administrator?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try using [`path`](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html)

```
path D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: Tried this, and seeing the path where grunt was just installed, but still command is not recognized.